# Ubuntu Virtual machine slows down the entire home network

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, vmware

I installed Xubuntu 13.10 in VMware Workstation and when it's on, Other people using the same network say it's being slow. I shut it down and then it's fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean with Slow ? so you mean Internet speed or the overall Network performance ?

Comment: Idk what the difference is but what's happening is webpages load very slowly, Online video game servers lag, Etc

Comment: It seems that you have auto update enabled in your VM and its running download in the background is consuming your bandwidth..... just give it some time -overnight perhaps; to finish and everything will be as good as  it was